# Return all reachable states in a DFA starting from the initial state

Tags: haskell, dfa

I'm trying to write a program in Haskell that returns a list of reachable states starting from the initial state, similar to a depth first search.

```
states_reachable :: Eq st => DFA st -> [st]
states_reachable (qs, sigma, delta, s, inF) =
    [delta q a | q <- qs, a <- sigma]
```

Note:

- **qs** is the set of states
- **sigma** is the alphabet
- **delta** is a transition function that takes a state and a symbol and returns the next state
- **s** is the initial state
- **inF** is a function that returns true if the state is an accepting state, false otherwise

As the function is defined now:

```
[delta q a | q <- qs, a <- sigma]
```

returns all the states in the DFA (which is incorrect).

What I would like is to populate the list by starting at the initial state **s** and testing the delta function with each input.

For example:

```
// returns the states reachable from the initial state for all symbols in sigma
[delta s a | a <- sigma]
```

The next step would be to repeat the process for each new state added to the list. This might add duplicates, but I can remove them later.

Then I tried:

```
[delta q a | q <- [delta s a | a <- sigma], a <- sigma]
```

I thought this might work, but it doesn't because it's creating the inner list and then using it to populate the outer list and then stopping.

I need to recursively build this list by exploring all the new states returned by the delta function.

Comment: Reminds me of this paper http://matt.might.net/papers/might2011derivatives.pdf and also you can look at the TDFA implementation for inspiration how to implement in Haskell https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to compute the transitive closure of a relation here, where the relation is "x can get to y in one step". As such, I'd suggest using a generic transitive-closure solution, rather than a DFA-specific one, and then produce that relation from your DFA. Here's one fairly basic way to do it:

```
module Closure (closure) where                                                  
import Data.List (nub)

closure :: Eq a => (a -> [a]) -> a -> [a]
closure nexts init = go [init]
  where go xs = let xs' = nub $ xs ++ (xs >>= nexts)                            
                in if xs == xs'                                                 
                   then xs                                                      
                   else go xs'
```

The algorithm here is to have a list of reachable states, and at each step expand it by walking from each to all its nearest neighbors, and then `nub` the list to get rid of duplicates. Once that expansion step adds no new nodes, you're done.

Now, how to map your DFA problem onto this? It's not too hard: you just need to produce a `nexts` function using `sigma` and `delta`. Here we need to assume that your DFA `delta` function is total, ie that every node has a transition specified for every letter in `sigma`. This is easy enough by creating one additional "failure" node that all nodes can transition to if they don't like their input, so I'll just assume that's been done.

```
neighbors :: (node -> letter -> node) -> [letter] -> node -> [node]             
neighbors delta sigma n = map (delta n) sigma
```

With that in place, your original problem reduces to:

```
closure (neighbors delta sigma) s
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a nicer way to write `closure` with `iterate` or `unfoldr` or something higher-level than `if`, but when I tried it turned out really messy.